# What is the purpose of RTLD_NODELETE and RTLD_NOLOAD in a dynamic library?

Tags: c, linux, shared-libraries, dynamic-linking

Code for the dynamic library `libone.so`:

```
void a()
{
    printf("--in libone.so a() invoked.\n");
}
```

Code for the application that uses the dynamic library:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <dlfcn.h>

int main()
{
        printf("in main.\n");
        void (*fptr)();
        void *ptr;

        //      here i used RTLD_NODELETE to available in memory after dlclose().

        ptr = dlopen("/root/Desktop/lsp-prac/dyn_lib/libone.so",RTLD_NOW|RTLD_NODELETE);
        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
                printf("dlopen:%s\n",dlerror() );
                return 0;
        }
        else
                printf("dlopen:success.\n" );

        fptr = dlsym(ptr,"a");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
                printf("dlsym:%s\n",dlerror() );
                return 0;
        }
        else
                printf("dlsym:success.\n" );

        (fptr)();       //indirect call

        printf("dlclose ptr:success.\n" );
        dlclose(ptr);                   //libone.so available in memory b'coz of RTLD_NODELETE.


        ptr = dlopen("libone.so",RTLD_NOW|RTLD_NOLOAD); // again linking libone.so from memory using RTLD_NOLOAD
        if(ptr == NULL)
        {
                printf("dlopen2:%s\n",dlerror() );
                return 0;
        }
        else
                printf("dlopen2:success.\n" );

        fptr = dlsym(ptr,"a");
        if(fptr == NULL)
        {
                printf("dlsym:%s\n",dlerror() );
                return 0;
        }
        else
                printf("dlsym:success.\n" );

        (fptr)();       //indirect call

        dlclose(ptr);
}
```

Here, based on my understanding `dlopen` will link the library from memory if it exists, but if it doesn't exist, it loads it from secondary storage and links to the executable.

But when I use RTLD_NODELETE and RTLD_NOLOAD then its giving the following error:

```
dlopen2:libone.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

Full output:

```
in main.
dlopen:success.
dlsym:success.
--in libone.so a() invoked.
dlclose ptr:success.
dlopen2:libone.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

What is the actual purpose of RTLD_NOLOAD & RTLD_NODELETE here?

Comment: It's possible that the loading is based on the path-name, which means you must provide the exact same path as given in the first `dlopen` call.

Comment: path is belongs to secondary storage but my library already available in primary memory so path is not required.     if i mentioned a path to library then what is use of RTLD_NOLOAD?.

Comment: The path you use when loading the library might act as a key. To find the library again you need to use the full key (the full path).

Comment: Which part of `man 3 dlopen` is problematic? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlopen.3.html Also the path-name does matter, because the loader will verify library identity on device and inode-number which are determined via `stat(filename)`

Answer (score 1):

The dynamic loader won't consider two shared objects to be equal just because their filenames are the same (`/root/Desktop/lsp-prac/dyn_lib/libone.so` and `libone.so`.

It's the device and inode number (cf `stat(2)`) that should be the same to consider the two files to be the same.

For example, if I create a shared object by name `/foo/libbar.so`, load it into a program via `dlopen`, then delete the file and create *another* `/foo/libbar.so`, it won't be the same file; dlopen will know that the new shared object has nothing to do with the previous one (as their *inode-numbers* are different).

Comment: Can you elaborate bit more,because the library is already in specific memory address so why it cant fetch from that address? why its again required fullpath.? -@Lorinczy Zsigmond

Comment: @JigneshParmar You seem to assume that the net filename is the key to identify a shared object. Well, it isn't. I might extend the answer to explain more clearly.

Comment: To add to the answer, what if the program loads `/foo/libone.so` *and* `/bar/libone.so`. Which library would `libone.so` (without path) refer to?